# AIX multihomed multicast

Tags: networking, ip, aix, multicast

On my AIX machine if I run `netstat -ia` I get:

```
Name  Mtu   Network     Address           Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
en0   1500  link#2      1e.18.1.1e.78.2    385229     0  1091655     0     0
                        01:00:5e:7f:ff:fd
                        01:00:5e:00:00:01
en0   1500  10.22.8     xxxxxxx1           385229     0  1091655     0     0
                        239.255.255.253    
                        224.0.0.1          
en1   1500  link#3      1e.18.1.1e.78.3   1045023     0   420863     0     0
                        01:00:5e:00:00:01
en1   1500  10.21.8     xxxxxxx2           1045023     0   420863     0     0
                        224.0.0.1          
en2   1500  link#4      1e.18.1.1e.78.4     59125     0    58326     0     0
                        01:00:5e:00:00:01
en2   1500  10.21.16    xxxxxxx3            59125     0    58326     0     0
                        224.0.0.1          
lo0   16896 link#1                         778096     0   586450     0     0
lo0   16896 127         loopback           778096     0   586450     0     0
                        239.192.0.0        
                        224.0.0.1          
lo0   16896 ::1%1                          778096     0   586450     0     0
                        ff01::1          
                        ff02::1:ff00:1
```

I'm testing a cluster application using multicast for communicating with other peers, anyway it seems to work only if I use as interface address the `lo0`. I cannot understand why....I'm using `239.192.0.0`for multicast.

Can anyone give me some explanation?

Comment: Have you tried a simple multicast test on other interfaces?